# URL amigável com Boilerplate

Tags: php, htaccess, boilerplate

Estou utilizando o Boilerplate para ter um template de base para uso. Porém estou tentando usar URL's amigáveis nele, mas não consigo..
Já tentei diversos códigos, o mais recente é este:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`
```

Aqui está o conteúdo do meu .htacess
http://pastebin.com/JT9gXdG2

Mas não estou conseguindo resultados satisfatórios! Só quero retirar a extensão .php dos meus links...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você ativou o mod_rewrite.c?

Caso sim. Na pasta(raiz) do site, cria um arquivo chamado:

`.htaccess`:

```
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
   RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]
```

---

Ativando o `mod_rewrite`:

1. Abre o arquivo `httpd.conf`, pesquise por `mod_rewrite.so` e descomente removendo o `#` no inicio da linha.
2. Procure por`AllowOverride None` e renomeia para `AllowOverride All`.

Comment: Sim amigo, na linha 212 do meu .htacess tem isso:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
  # Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    RewriteEngine On
  # RewriteBase /
</IfModule>`

Comment: Atualizado o post. Coloquei como ativar o `mod_rewrie`.

Comment: Infelizmente não estou achando o httpd.conf aqui no host.. Conhece alguma outra maneira?